# How to Disable lambda feature in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda

I have added some dependency in my Gradle few days ago, but don't know which now android studio always suggesting me for **xx can be replaced with lambda.** How do I disable this feature such it studio will be not suggestion for this **Replace with Lambda?**

Issue: Android studio showing replaceable code as disabled (brown colored but works correctly) with only showing replace with lambda.

Comment: The suggestions are showing to you because you set compileOptions to JAVA 8

Comment: @Sofia Gray is the answer below helping to figuring out the issue? If so, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are talking about `Anonymous classes` then you can disable this suggestion from Android Studio's settings:

`Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`, then search for
`Anonymous type can be replaced with lambda` and disable the checkbox.

On the same Inspections section you can enabled/disable other AS replacement suggestions.

Tested with AS 3.5